# How do I get access to ToolBar or InputAccessoryView that appears on top of keyboard without using textfield instance

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uikeyboard, iqkeyboardmanager, toolbaritems

Whenever keyboard appears in the project , I can find that by adding observer to **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification**.

But I want to get access to the tool bar that appears on top of the keyboard globally from not from every viewcontroller

**Background:**

I am using **IQKeyboardManager** and I am setting buttons on top of the keyboard using it.

IQKeyboardManager doesn't make the tool bar available for external access.

So I'm wondering if there's any way to get access to the keyboard whenever it appears and iterate the items of toolbar that's on top of the keyboard.

Any tips are welcome

**Update:**

The problem comes from the source code in the POD.

**IQUIView+IQKeyboardToolbar.m**

```
  {
  //Flexible space
   [items addObject:[[self class] flexibleBarButtonItem]];
   
   //Title button
   toolbar.titleBarButton.title = titleText;
   if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {}
   else
   {
       toolbar.titleBarButton.customView.frame = CGRectZero;
   }

   [items addObject:toolbar.titleBarButton];
   
   //Flexible space
   [items addObject:[[self class] flexibleBarButtonItem]];
    }
```

Because of the above code in their pod

even though there's no title text in tool bar , it's still being added as an item on the toolbar and so when we turn on the accessibility the empty title button is read as Dimmed button.

I have the fix

```
   if(titleText){
   //Flexible space
   [items addObject:[[self class] flexibleBarButtonItem]];
   
   //Title button
   toolbar.titleBarButton.title = titleText;
   if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {}
   else
   {
       toolbar.titleBarButton.customView.frame = CGRectZero;
   }

   [items addObject:toolbar.titleBarButton];
   
   //Flexible space
   [items addObject:[[self class] flexibleBarButtonItem]];
   }else{
   [items addObject:[[self class] flexibleBarButtonItem]];
   [items addObject:[[self class] flexibleBarButtonItem]];
   [items addObject:[[self class] flexibleBarButtonItem]];

   }
```

But we can't fix their pod from our side.

So I'm wondering if I could get access of the the tool bar above keyboard , then I can effectively remove the empty item and add the items back into the tool bar again and this would fix my problem.

Comment: Have you looked at [`inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview)?

Comment: Yes but I can't go and assign for every text field in the project

Comment: Please update your question with some relevant code. Also clearly explain why you need to access the toolbar above the keyboard. You state that you set buttons using `IQKeyboardManager`. If you are already setting those buttons, why do you need to get access to those buttons when the keyboard appears?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it looks to me like you can use something like `IQKeyboardManager.shared.textFieldView.keyboardToolbar` to access the accessory views. You'll probably need to unwrap some optional values in there. It's nice that you can just look at the IQKeyboardManager code (some of it here: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/blob/master/IQKeyboardManagerSwift/IQKeyboardManager%2BToolbar.swift).

Comment: Another option is to traverse the view hierarchy, but I wouldn't really recommend it. BTW, IMO, there is no "canonical answer" for this. Typically, I would argue against doing something like this globally. (And certainly you should keep this code out of the AppDelegate!) But I could maybe see writing some kind of "keyboard service" in the app, that does exist at a global level, and handles this sort of thing.

Comment: @HangarRash - I can set buttons..that's not a problem. but I have not set the title button for tool bar..but when it reads the tool bar.. it falsely reads the title button as Dimmed Button.

Comment: @livingtech - I couldn't find any textFieldView reference in `IQKeyboardManager.shared`

Comment: @Shajo 1. Report a bug on the project's Github page. 2. Fork your own copy of the project with your fix. Use that in your project until the main project resolves the issue. 3. Please redo your question. Your added code makes it clear what your issue is. But the whole first half of the question makes it sound like a completely different issue.

Comment: @HangarRash - it's going to take lots of time for them to make any new release based on the filed bug report and forking and fixing is fine but we have a rule that we can add external library through PODs only so I can't import the cloned and corrected version into my project

Comment: @HangarRash - The first part of the question would lead me to a fix

Comment: But you already have a fix. A much simper fix. The first part of your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) description. Your question should point out the actual problem, not ask about implementing one possible solution.

Comment: @HangarRash - I've edited the question , now it's clear I guess

Comment: @HangarRash - Like I said the fix i can do only inside the downloaded pod files but we have kept all the pods under gitignore because we don't want to version the pod changes in our company Git. That's why I'm looking to apply the same fix..but all I need is access to toolbar globally then I will be able to apply my fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly urge you to work the patched framework into your build environment since you already know the fix to the framework. Doing so avoids the need to change any of your app's code.

However, the following code could be used as a temporary workaround until the framework is fixed (if ever) by the framework author. The following makes it simple to get access to the `inputAccessoryView` of any text field or text view in your app each time the text field or text view becomes first responder.

Add these two lines to your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

Objective-C:

```objective-c
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(beginEditingHandler:) name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(beginEditingHandler:) name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
```

Swift:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(beginEditingHandler), name: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(beginEditingHandler), name: UITextView.textDidBeginEditingNotification, object: nil)
```

And add this method to your app delegate class:

Objective-C:

```objective-c
- (void)beginEditingHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIResponder *responder = notification.object;
    UIView *inputAccessoryView = responder.inputAccessoryView;
    if (inputAccessoryView) {
        // Process the inputAccessoryView as needed
    }
}
```

Swift:

```swift
@objc func beginEditingHandler(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let responder = notification.object as? UIResponder, let inputAccessoryView = responder.inputAccessoryView {
        // Process the inputAccessoryView as needed
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with the framework you are using so I don't know how to get the toolbar from the input accessory view. It could be as simple as trying to cast `inputAccessoryView as? UIToolbar` or you might have to see if there is a subview of `inputAccessoryView` that is a `UIToolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have an external dependency which you cannot change (because it will take a while to upstream your fix into their official release) but you have a fix you want in their code right now.

So one way to workaround it, whilst staying within your working practices, is to have an Xcode build script phase in your project which 'patches' the files of the Pod before compilation.  See the command `/usr/bin/diff` and `/usr/bin/patch` for creating and applying patches.

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont want to do it via `inputAccessoryView` then you can do it via `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` observer and get the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` from the notification's `userInfo` dictionary to get the frame of the keyboard and From there you can get the frame of the input accessory view and do any modifications on it.

c'mon, it's not that hard

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // to listen for notification when keyboard appears
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
        selector: @selector(handleNotification:) 
        name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
        object: nil];
}

// when keyboard appears to handle it
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // notification's userInfo dictionary to get frame of the keyboard
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    
    // get input accessory view from current first responder
    UIView *inputAccessoryView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].firstResponder.inputAccessoryView;
    
    // now its accessed, make changes
    inputAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
    // remove observer
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: So can you explain me how do you get the access of inputaccessoryview instance now

Comment: @Shajo updated. Just make sure to handle any potential edge cases, like if there is no first responder active or if the input accessory view is not present for some reason

Comment: `UIApplication keyWindow` has been deprecated since iOS 13 due to the support of scenes.

Comment: @HangarRash we can still use `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes`  to loop through window scenes, or if you have some workaround

Comment: @AfzalK. But which scene (and window) do you choose? On an iPad you can easily have multiple scenes open in an app.

Comment: @HangarRash we will check the activationState of each scene with UISceneActivationStateForegroundActive , which means that its window is the key window for the app, there is no workaround for now, its tricky, we have to loop through

Comment: @AfzalK - I appreciate your effort.